# Groupby, aggregate and check the condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I am supposed to aggregate the values in number column for each country and check if it is greater than or equal to 2. If true, it should be displayed as a column in my data.

Dataset

```
Country             Number   bool

India               1        yes
India               0        no
India               2        no
India               0        yes
Germany             1        no
Germany             0        no
Germany             0        yes
Japan               2        yes
Japan               0        yes
```

Expected Output

```
Country             Number   bool   result

India               1        yes     3
India               0        no      3
India               2        no      3
India               0        yes     3
Japan               2        yes     2
Japan               0        yes     2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So in your case do `trasnform` with `groupby` then filter it

```
df['result'] = df.groupby('Country')['Number'].transform('sum')
df = df.query('result>=2')
df
Out[18]: 
  Country  Number bool  result
0   India       1  yes       3
1   India       0   no       3
2   India       2   no       3
3   India       0  yes       3
7   Japan       2  yes       2
8   Japan       0  yes       2
```